# how to create matrix/array of array with fix number of rows and non-fixed number of columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

here am trying to create mtrix with fixed number of rows and non-fixed number of columns like bellow.

```
var matrix=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0 ]]
```

am trying this code

```
function matrix1(m, n) {
    for (  m = 9;m>0;m--)
    {
        for (var n=m;n>0; n--)
        {   
             return Array.from({  
                 length: m
              }, () => new Array(n).fill(0));
        }
        document.write("<br>");      
    }      
};

var cols=9
var counter=9;
matrix(counter,cols);
```

and am expecting the output of this code is as like

```
var matrix=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0],
            [0]]
```

and am getting output as

```
var matrix=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just small modification in your code

```
function matrix(m, n) {
 var arr = [];
 for (  m = 9; m>0; m--)
    {
      for (var n = m;n>0; n--)
         {
           arr.push(new Array(n).fill(0))
         }
       return arr;
    }  
 };

var cols=9
var counter=9;
console.log(matrix(counter,cols));
```

This will work

Working live example : https://jsbin.com/?html,js,output

Hope this helps. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks,@KrishCdbry

Comment: Most Welcome @M56035G :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `array.map` and `array.fill`

```js
function createMatrix(m, n) {
  return new Array(m).fill('').map(function(el, index) {
    return n > index ? new Array(n - index).fill(0) : [];
  });
}
console.log(createMatrix(7, 7))
```

Comment: this is exclt what i was trying,but this code create minimum column sized array with 3,what if i want it till 1

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh it is realy helpfull